# Turning an affirmative statement into a question

Tags: sentence-construction

> Are the budget airlines in a different strategic group than the major
>   network airlines?

Is it a correct sentence? If I rewrite this sentence in an affirmative form, it could be

> The budget airlines are in a different strategic group than the major network airlines.

But my question is about after linking verb **are** (before preposition **in**) whether something is required or not?

My question is about whether something is required between the words **are** and **in**. If I say:

> I'm better at English than Karim.

that would be a correct sentence. But if I say

> I'm _______ at English than Karim

then a question arises:

> I'm ... what? ... at English than Karim.

Something, I mean an adjective (like *better*), is required between **am** and **at**.

Comment: Although the following link doesn't bear directly on your question, it is relevant: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/different-from-than-or-to

Answer (score 1):

When you change the sentence from a question to a statement, nothing is *required* between 'are' and 'in'.  As you know, the word order is what determines whether it is a question or not.

You *can* add an adverb between the verb and preposition if needed.

> The budget airlines are **often** in a different strategic group ...
>
> The budget airlines are **always** in a different strategic group ...

But that will change the meaning of the sentence at least a little.

Answer (score 1):

The affirmative sentence is in SVO order (well, SVC order because *to be* is a linking verb, but the distinction between an object and a complement is not important here).

As is common with a question, you have shifted it to VSO order.

The verb is *are*, the subject is *the budget airlines*, and the complement is "*in a different strategic group than the major network airlines*".

This a completely **normal** case of changing word order to make something a question. It needs **no special treatment**. You have thus formed the question **correctly**.